# Exoplayer cast extension with live streams

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying the implement cast support to my androapp, when I use normal non live links such as MP4 and even HLS non live stream it works perfectly but, when I use live stream the stream just won't play at the chromecast.

This is how I create my MediaInfo:

```
           MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
        movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Test");

MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("HLS link")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE).setContentType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata).build();
```

This is how I load the items:

```
castPlayer.loadItem(new MediaQueueItem.Builder(setCastMedia()).build(), 0);
```

This is the logcat I get:

```
W/MediaControlChannel: received unexpected error: Invalid Request. W/MediaQueue: Error fetching queue item ids, statusCode=2100, statusMessage=null
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Happens the same with TS type streams...

Comment: What is the live stream URL ? it may have CORS

Comment: Can't post a link at the moment, but if it has CORS what should be different?

Comment: if in this header there is a restriction access-control-allow-origin:  you cannot access stream. Can you play any one stream ? or none

Comment: You can also try adding -->> .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL") <<--- it is working for me in the defaul Video View with live streams

Comment: MimeTypes class is your custom class ?

Comment: You solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, you can cast live streams using ExoPlayer.

```
MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_TV_SHOW);
movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title");

MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("your_link.m3u8")
                                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                                .setContentType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                                .build();

MediaQueueItem mediaQueueItem = new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build();

castPlayer.loadItem(mediaQueueItem, mediaQueueItem.getMedia().getStreamDuration());
castPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```